# angularのngresourceでPOSTした場合のRequest URLについて

Tags: angularjs

angularのngresourceを使って、POSTした場合に連携したリクエストパラメータが、
Request URLに含まれてしまいます。

例）
{user_id:1}をパラメータとして連携した場合
Request URL下記のようになります。

`http://hogehoge?user_id=1`

リクエストパレラメータをRequest URLに含めない方法あるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

下記の２件がngresourceでbodyでパラメーターを送っているので、そちらを参考にしてみてください。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203646/send-request-body-on-resource
http://www.walbrix.com/jp/blog/2014-03-angularjs-form-urlencoded.html